# Google Drive quit command executable

Tags: backup, sync, google-drive, windows-task-scheduler

Just finished setting up task scheduler(win10) to boot up Google Drive off hours to avoid resource drag specifically when syncing third party backup images.

All's good with the backup app scheduler and booting up Google Drive but I need the Google executable for the "quit" command found in GD>Preferences.

Without it, after the the GD sync task runs it will leave GD running and I'm back to square one with GD syncing during work hours and draining resources.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: Schedule 2nd task to shutdown Win10 after 1st task;G Drive sync & 3rd task for next morning startup.